# writing a char array in line with white spaces

Tags: c

The problem is to input some n elements in a line and make an array in c language. The format of input is This.

input:

15 //number of elements

1 4 4 2 3 5 6 x x x x x x 5 7 // elements

I tried it by using a scanf function, but it didn't work.

```
char* tree;
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
tree = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf("%c", &tree[i]);
}
```

what's the problem of this code?

- also i tried another version,

```
int * tree;
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
tree = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf("d", &tree[i]);
}
```

but i failed because of char "x".

Comment: There are about 30 characters in `"1 4 4 2 3 5 6 x x x x x x 5 7\n"`, not 15.  Try adding a space `scanf(" %c", &tree[i]);` to not scan and save white-space.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is fine, the only thing is that you seems to have 15 characters separated by spaces as input, but you read the first 8 plus the 7 spaces between them. Just correct the scanf

```
scanf(" %c", &tree[i]);
```

Also since `n` is going to be a small number, I think you can safely use VLA

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    char tree[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n && scanf(" %c", &tree[i]) == 1; i++);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica you are right, I changed that